# Java: Read COM port when button pressed

Tags: java, serial-port

I want to read data from a weighbridge terminal that is connected via a serial port. I want to read data when user presses the 'Read Weight' button. What can be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a library such as the [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) to access your serial ports.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking whether to handle serialEvent or do something else. I want to populate a field from port data when a button is pressed. One option is that I read data whenever available (serialEvent), and store that data in a variable, then populate the field from this variable when user presses button. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Whether some thing is “better” than some other thing depends on your requirements and situation, e.g. does the device always send data or only on your request? If the device can generate data without you requesting it you should read it as soon as it is produced; you might want to include a function in your buffering to discard all input read until a specific point in time (e.g. the time you actually want to request the data).